# How can I fix a permission issue with SpreadsheetApp.openById in appscript on Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have been trying to use appscript function on googlesheets cell, everything works if I give the results as return in function. but when i try to call spreadsheetapp and edit cell it says i dont have permission.

I have been trying to experiment with appscript and sheet.

script:

```
function ifzero(a){
  if (a==0){
    return "";
  }
  return a; 
}
```

works:
sheet Cell: =ifzero(1)
result: 1

But Script:

```
function test() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1uXdFFlmRlu7m6-1FAbNtnVU2OjrXVLTRZMWk31gKRP4');
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var range = sheet.getRange(1,1);
  range.setValue('TRUE');
}
```

Doesn't work;
sheet Cell = test()
error:Exception: You do not have permission to call SpreadsheetApp.openById. Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets (line 5).

even after running the function via script and giving it permission

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions?hl=en#using_services

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Custom functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) run in a restricted context and cannot use methods that require authorization. `SpreadsheetApp.openById()` and `Range.setValue()` require authorization and will thus not work in a custom function.

The easiest way to make it work is to call the function through some other means, such as a [button](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus#clickable_images_and_drawings_in_google_sheets), a [custom menu item](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus), a [sidebar](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#custom_sidebars) or an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable).

Comment: Thanks good to know that its not possible. Otherwise I would be wasting my time searching a way.